# Java wrong username & password message cant seem to work

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, netbeans

This is the coding on a button of jFrame a simple login form, username and password authentication working fine but if else condition dont execute i am stuck here if any of you guys help me out here just give me a hint

```
String u_id=jTextField1.getText();
String p_word=jPasswordField1.getText();
        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName=LoginForm; user=sa; password=aptech");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result=st.executeQuery("select pass_word from employee where user_name='"+u_id+"'  ");

         if(result.next())
        {

          String pwd =  result.getString("pass_word");

           if( p_word.equals(pwd))
           {
                jLabel4.setText("you are logged in");
           }
           else if (!p_word.equals(pwd))
           {
                jLabel4.setText("Your id password is Wrong");
           }

        }
        else 
        {
            jLabel4.setText("Enter your id password again");
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jPasswordField1.setText("");
        }       
     }            
     catch (ClassNotFoundException a)
     {
          System.out.println(""+a);
     }
     catch (SQLException s)
     {
          System.out.println(""+s);
     }
```

Comment: `if else condition dont execute ` How? Does the program exit? Does it throw an exception? What happens? What does the program output?

Comment: you can change "else if (!p_word.equals(pwd))" to "else"

Comment: Please add some punctuation to your question... Do you mean `if else condition dont execute. i am stuck here` or `if else condition dont execute, i am stuck here`? They are different problems.

Comment: Do not build SQL strings from user input. Your code has a massive SQL injection hole.

Comment: I hate waiting for clarifications! it seems that the OP is less interested in answers than SO Users in clarifications !

Comment: no the 'else' condition  didnt execute but i did solve the problem thanks :)

Comment: @millimoose i know this is a simple test coding , thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead:

Create a new class called (I hope you're using and IDE!) "Log.java"
Copy & Paste following code into the class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Log extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Log frameTable = new Log();
}

JButton Login = new JButton("Login");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);

Log(){
super("Login Autentification");
setSize(300,200);
setLocation(500,280);
panel.setLayout (null); 


txuser.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
pass.setBounds(70,65,150,20);
Login.setBounds(110,100,80,20);

panel.add(Login);
panel.add(txuser);
panel.add(pass);

getContentPane().add(panel);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
actionlogin();
}

public void actionlogin(){
Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
String puname = txuser.getText();
String ppaswd = pass.getText();
if(puname.equals("1") && ppaswd.equals("2")) {
newframe regFace =new newframe();
regFace.setVisible(true);
dispose();
} else {

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password or Username!");
txuser.setText("");
pass.setText("");
txuser.requestFocus();
}

}
});
}
}
```

Then, create a new class, "newframe.java", and fill it with this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class newframe extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
newframe frameTabel = new newframe();
}

JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to a New Frame");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

newframe(){
super("Welcome");
setSize(300,200);
setLocation(500,280);
panel.setLayout (null); 

welcome.setBounds(70,50,150,60);

panel.add(welcome);

getContentPane().add(panel);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Now you should be good to go, if something is not clear, feel free to ask or figure out by yourself, this lovely community will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have about ten time more code than you need. Do this instead (pseudo code):

Use this query instead:

```
select count(*)
from employee
where user_name = ?
and pass_word = ?
```

You will get exactly one row with one column returned.
The value of that column will be either `1` or `0`

You should be able to handle the rest by yourself.